# Are there any open source tools to convert GitHub actions into azure pipelines?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, github-actions

Are there any open source tools to convert GitHub actions into azure pipelines? I was able to find the tool which can convert pipeline yaml into actions yaml but not the other way around. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: As of this time, however, I'm afraid that there is no open source tools to convert GitHub actions into azure pipelines.

Comment: could you link the tool you found for converting Azure pipeline yaml to github actions?